# 3 box layout in css

Tags: html, css

New here, I am making a web page for a school project and am having trouble getting the layout the way I want. was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

- I am creating a layout. The top of the page is the navigation, then I have one main large image with some content over lay, and under that I have an image with content overlayed on the left and the right, then at the bottom the footer. * or thats what I would like anyway.

I have tried putting the images each in a  but I can only get them to either be in a column or stacked. As I would like the first image under the header with navigation to be a wider picture , then two smaller ones each half the width of the main wider image if that makes sense..

I have searched online and the only things that looks similar to what I'm trying to accomplish are pay for templates.

```html
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="thebean.jpg" />
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="rooftops.jpg" />
            <div id="topleft"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="thebean.jpg" />
            <div id="topright"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if i got your question right without a figure that help me figure out the layout you are looking for.

Give a look at this picture and tell me if i got it right or not!

[Layout testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvXCu.jpg)

Here is the simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="largerPanel">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/49/54/aa4954451f16847cb657e68e5f46538a.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="floatPanel" class="halfPanel">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fB8MYCGFqC0/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="halfPanel">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ8nIMQ30DM-OKazFBcLM4m9kq3_fzph-eBoiax6M88O5nncGyB">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.css

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.halfPanel{
    width:50%;
    height: 20%;
}

.halfPanel img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#floatPanel{
    float:right;
}

#largerPanel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
#largerPanel img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If i got it wrong please post a simple paint image with some boxes that show the layout you want, i will be happy to help you through this!

Comment: OMG yes! Thank you so much. This is exactly what i was trying to do. I know im still learning but thank you so much!

Comment: it's all good mate, we all started from zero. There is nothing wrong in asking for help. Glad i could help, please accept the answer if your problem is solved. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers